# Is there a way to tell keepalived to make a health check immediately?

Tags: lvs, keepalived, healthcheck

We have a high-availability setup in which [lvs](/questions/tagged/lvs) distributes requests between a set of backend servers ('realservers' in LVS-speak). LVS is managed by [keepalived](/questions/tagged/keepalived). Each realserver exposes a health check resource over HTTP (basically, if you say `GET /info/health` to one of them, it will respond with either `healthy` or `ill`), and keepalived is configured to poll these resources every 15 seconds to check realserver health. If a realserver becomes unhealthy, keepalived zeroes its weight in the virtual server table, so no traffic is sent to it. All fairly normal stuff, i believe.

Sometimes, it would be really useful to tell keepalived to make a health check for a specific realserver (or all the realservers in a specific service) *right now*, rather than waiting for the next 15-second point. Is there any way to do this?

For us, this would be useful during deployment operations, where we want to have a new realserver health-checked and added to the pool right away, rather than waiting for it to happen naturally.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done by sending the `HUP` signal:

```
pkill -HUP keepalived
```

Comment: I think that makes keepalived re-read is configuration file. Does that then cause an immediate health check? If it does, it will necessarily be a check of everything, which is not what i was asking for.

Comment: Of course `HUP` will do more than you were asking for, but why would rereading the configuration file and checking everything do any harm? Have you tried it?